# backbone collection. "load more" button

Tags: backbone.js

Im quite new to backbone and trying to add an "load more"-button toe the project. I want the button to load lets say six new items from my collection every time it gets clicked. How would i implement that?

Right now i have the whole collection loaded when the view initziales. But i guess it would be better to just load six items? (the ones that will be visible) and then i want to append six new ones on every click on "load more".

Anyone the can show me/help me on this one?

Collection

```
define([
'Underscore',
'Backbone',
'app',
'VideoModel',
], function (_, Backbone, app, VideoModel) {

var VideoCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({  
    model: VideoModel,  
    url: url,
    parse: function (response) {
        return response;
    },
    initialize: function() {

    }    
}); 
return VideoCollection;
```

});

Model

```
define([
'Underscore',
'Backbone',
'app',
```

], function (_, Backbone, app) {

```
var VideoModel = Backbone.Model.extend({  
    defaults: function() {  
        return {
            data: {
                id: "",
                created: "",
                timestamp: ""
            }
        };
    },  
    clear: function() {  
        this.destroy();  
    }
}); 
return VideoModel;
```

});

View

```
define([
'Underscore',
'Backbone',
'app',
'VideoCollection'
```

], function (_, Backbone, app, VideoCollection) {

```
var StartView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: "section",
    id: "start",
    className: "content",

    events: {

    },
    initialize: function(){
        $(".container").html(this.el);
        this.template = _.template($("#start_template").html(), {} );
        this.collection = new VideoCollection();
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template);
        this.collection.fetch({
            success: function (obj) {
                var json = obj.toJSON()

                for(var i=0; i<json.length; i++) {

                }
            }
        });
    },
    kill: function() {
        this.remove(); 
    }
});
return StartView;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the best thing to do is use 2 instances of the same collection. One that has all the models in it, and one that just has visible models in it. You can bind your view to the 'visible' collection, and when you click load more, just copy models from your complete collection to your visible collection. I'm not going to write the code for this, as your `StartView` as it stands needs a bit of refactoring, I would try and do the following with your view:

- Remove your `collection.fetch` and `render` calls from your view, and move them into an object which controls your application, sets up your views etc. That way the view is quite a dumb object, it knows about it's DOM elements, the collection it needs to render, and that's about it.
- Don't use the `fetch` success callback. A successful call to `fetch` will result in either `add` or `remove` event's being fired. You can bind to these event's like so:

`this.collection = new VideoCollection();`

`this.collection.bind('add remove', this.render, this);`

`this.collection.fetch();`